# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping when mapping is registered

Tags: c#, automapper

I've been reading similar questions regarding this problem but I can't seem to understand the solution.

I'm trying to map my entity to my view model and I noticed that it fails for some of my entities. An example would be the following:

**Entity**

```
public class Warehouse : EntityBase
{
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public Warehouse()
    {

    }
}

public abstract class EntityBase : IConcurrencyEnabled
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class WarehouseVM : VMBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual AddressVM Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocationVM> Locations { get; set; }

    public WarehouseVM()
    {

    }
}  

public abstract class VMBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(this TSource entity)
    where TSource : class
    where TDestination : class, new()
{
    IMapper mapper = Core.Container.Get<IMapper>();

    return mapper.Map<TDestination>(entity);
}
```

**Usage**

```
WMAS.Data.Entities.Warehouse warehouse = viewModel.Item.Map<WarehouseVM, WMAS.Data.Entities.Warehouse>();
```

**Exception**

[image: Exception]

> [AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or
>   unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: WarehouseVM -> Warehouse WMAS.Shared.Models.WarehouseVM
>   -> WMAS.Data.Entities.Warehouse]    lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext ) +468
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(Object source) +603
>   WMAS.Web.Extension.Map(TSource entity) in
>   c:\Users\tugadoje\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\JET.Project\WMAS.Web\Extensions\Extension.cs:40
>   WMAS.Web.Areas.Warehouse.Controllers.WarehouseController.Create(WarehouseCreateVM
>   viewModel) in c:\Users\tugadoje\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\JET.Project\WMAS.Web\Areas\Warehouse\Controllers\WarehouseController.cs:73
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +192
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +752
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +93
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +90    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +211
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +141
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c()
>   +189    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e()
>   +717    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +71
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +141
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19()
>   +103    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +330
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +71
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +73
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +90
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +188
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +73
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +85
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +73
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +50    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +93
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +188
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +73
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +58    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +59
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

I've made sure to register all my mappings. In my global.acx.cs I am calling `MapperConfig.RegisterMappings()`.

```
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperCfg { get; private set; }
    public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        MapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
            cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationUserDepartment, ApplicationUserDepartmentVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BasicInfo, BasicInfoVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<CityMunicipality, CityMunicipalityVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Country, CountryVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<DeliverySlip, DeliverySlipVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<DeliverySlipItem, DeliverySlipItemVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Department, DepartmentVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Image, ImageVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<InventBatch, InventBatchVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<InventLedger, InventLedgerVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Item, ItemVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<ItemCategory, ItemCategoryVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Location, LocationVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Module, ModuleVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Province, ProvinceVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<PurchaseOrderItem, PurchaseOrderItemVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Region, RegionVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<SalesInvoice, SalesInvoiceVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<SalesInvoiceItem, SalesInvoiceItemVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<SalesInvoicePayment, SalesInvoicePaymentVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Submodule, SubmoduleVM>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<SysConfig, SysConfigVM>().ReverseMap();
        });

        Mapper = MapperCfg.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is this part of the message towards the beginning:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: WarehouseVM -> Warehouse

You need to create the mapping to support this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<WarehouseVM , Warehouse>();
```

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer with respect to who answered first.

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells you what is wrong:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

and the missing mapping is:

> Warehouse WMAS.Shared.Models.WarehouseVM -> WMAS.Data.Entities.Warehouse

Inspecting your `MapperConfig` I see no mapping from `WarehousVM` to `Warehouse`. Adding the mapping should fix the problem.

Comment: I feel so dumb after reading the answers. Must have been too stressed to notice that one. I'm not sure which answer came first, yours or @AaronLS but I'll get back to this in 4 days after the holidays and testing it out.